# How to send a message to correct user. Laravel chats function using Pusher.ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

#What I want to do

I want to make a chats system using Laravel,Pusher,ajax.
If the login user is not the item user, a message is sent correctly.
But if I want to send a message to others on the item that made by the login user,
the message will be sent to login user.
I want to know how to fix this issue.But I have no idea...

Route

```
Route::get('/chats/{receive}/send/{itemId}', [ChatsController::class, 'sendChat'])->name('chats.users');
Route::post('chat/send' , [ChatsController::class, 'store'])->name('chatSend');
```

blade

```php
  <div class="px-4  bg-white text-right sm:px-6">
 <a href="{{ route('chats.users',['receive' => $item->user->id ,'itemId'=> $item->id ] ) }}" 
  type="submit" >チャット </a></div>
```

Controller

```php
    public function sendChat(Request $request,  $receive ,$itemId )
    {
     
        
        $loginId = Auth::id();
 
            $param = [
             'send' => $loginId,
             'receive' => $receive,
            ];

  
        $query = Message::where('send' , $loginId)->where('receive' , $receive);
        $query->orWhere(function($query) use($loginId , $receive){
            $query->where('send' , $receive);
            $query->where('receive' , $loginId);
 
        });

        $messages = $query->get();
        $user = User::where('id', $param['receive'])->get();
        $item = Item::findOrFail($itemId);

        return view('chats.sendChat' , compact('param' , 'messages','user','item'));
    }
 

    /**
     * Save message
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       
       
        $insertParam = [
            'send' => $request->input('send'),
            'receive' => $request->input('receive'),
            'message' => $request->input('message'),
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'item_id' => $request->input('item_id')
        ];

       
        try{
            Message::insert($insertParam);
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            return false;        
        }
        return true;
 
    }
```

messages table

```
 $table->id();
 $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
$table->foreignId('item_id')->constrained();
 $table->bigInteger('send')->comment('送信者');
 $table->bigInteger('receive')->comment('受信者');
 $table->text('message');
 $table->tinyInteger('is_read')->default(0);
 $table->timestamps();
```

chats.sendChat.blade.php

```php
@extends('layouts.app')
 
@section('content')
<div class="mt-4">
<div class="m-auto  px-4 py-5 mt-2 max-w-xl bg-white rounded-lg  " >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-start-2 col-span-4 ">
       
         
        </div>
    </div>
 
  
    <div id="room" class="justify-items-stretch">
     
      <h1 class="text-lg mb-2">
        <a class="no-underline hover:underline text-black" href="{{ route('users.items',[$user[0]->id]) }}">
          {{ $user[0]->name }}</a> 
          {{ $item->title }} 
       
    </h1>
      <hr>

     
    
        @foreach($messages as  $message)

            {{--   Send message  --}}
            @if($message->send == \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::id())
         <div class="flex items-end justify-end">
                <div class="send mr-2 bg-green-300 mx-1 my-1  px-1 rounded-lg" style="text-align: right">
                    <p>{{$message->message}}</p>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <p class="text-xs " style="text-align: right">{{ $message->user->name }}</p>
            @endif
 
            {{--   received message  --}}
            @if($message->receive == \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::id())
            <div class="flex items-start justify-start">
                <div class="receive mr-2 bg-gray-300 mx-1 my-1 px-1 rounded-lg" style="text-align: left">
                    <p >{{$message->message}}</p>
                    
                </div>
                </div>
                <p class="text-xs ">{{ $message->user->name }}</p>
            @endif

          
        @endforeach
       
    </div>
 
    <form  >
      @csrf
     
        <textarea name="message" style="width:100%" class="mt-1 p-1 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300  block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border border-indigo-600 rounded-xl"></textarea>
       
        <button type="button" id="btn_send" class="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-8 mt-1 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-xl text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none  focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 " style="float: right" >
        <svg
        class="w-4 h-4 transform rotate-45 -mt-px"
        fill="none"
        stroke="currentColor"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <path
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
          stroke-width="2"
          d="M12 19l9 2-9-18-9 18 9-2zm0 0v-8"
        ></path>
      </svg></button>
    
   
    </form>
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="{{$param['send']}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="receive" value="{{$param['receive']}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="login" value="{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::id()}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{$item->id}}">

</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var pusher = new Pusher('', {
cluster  : '',
encrypted: true
});


var pusherChannel = pusher.subscribe('chat');


pusherChannel.bind('chat_event', function(data) {

let appendText;
let login = $('input[name="login"]').val();

if(data.send === login){
appendText = '<div class="flex items-end justify-end"> <div class="send  bg-green-300 mx-1 my-1 p-1 rounded-lg " style="text-align:right"><p>' + data.message + '</p></div></div> ';
}else if(data.receive === login){
appendText = '<div class="receive bg-gray-300 w-3/4 mx-4 my-2 p-2 rounded-lg clearfix" style="text-align:left"><p>' + data.message + '</p></div> ';
}else{
return false;
}


$("#room").append(appendText);

if(data.receive === login){

Push.create("新着メッセージ",
{
    body: data.message,
    timeout: 8000,
    onClick: function () {
        window.focus();
        this.close();
    }
})
}
});


$.ajaxSetup({
headers : {
'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
}});


// メッセージ送信
$('#btn_send').on('click' , function(){
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : '/chat/send',
data : {
    message : $('textarea[name="message"]').val(),
    send : $('input[name="send"]').val(),
    receive : $('input[name="receive"]').val(),
    item_id : $('input[name="item_id"]').val(),
}
}).done(function(result){
$('textarea[name="message"]').val('');
}).fail(function(result){

});
});
       
 </script>
```